# Double absolute inequality

Tags: inequality

I wan to determine for which $x$ the following inequality holds
$$
|x-1| < |2x+3|
$$
Can somebody tell me how to approach this? Shall I analyze the following inequality
$$
-(2x+3) < x-1 < +(2x+3)
$$
jointly with this other one
$$
+(x-1) < 2x+3 < -(x-1) 
$$
If so, how I should proceed from there? Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918856

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

==========================================

Comment: What is this ============================== supposed to mean?!?!?!

Comment: I like this answer a lot ! If you don't understand something in mathematics, make an illustration, draw a graph. That is very good advice for students.

Comment: @M.Wind Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you square it (you can since both sides are nonegative) $$
|x-1|^2 < |2x+3|^2
$$
we get $$ 4x^2+12x+9>x^2-2x+1\implies 3x^2+14x+8>0$$

So $$(3x+2)(x+4)>0\implies x \in (-\infty,-4)\cup (-{2\over 3},\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

For $$x\geq 1$$ we get $$x-1<2x+3$$
and for $$-\frac{3}{2}\le x<1$$ we get $$-x+1<2x
+3$$
and so on!
Finally we get $$-\frac{2}{3}<x+\infty, -\infty<x<-4$$

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of inequalities we need to consider some cases, notably since the LHS and RHS are zero at $x=-\frac32$ and $x=1$ we can proceed as follows

- $x<-\frac32\implies   -x+1 < -2x-3$
- $-\frac32\le x<1\implies   -x+1 < 2x+3$
- $x\ge 1 \implies  1-x < 2x+3$

then we need to solve each inequality in the corresponding range and finally take tha union of the single solutions as final solution for the given inequality.